# How to decode utf-8 charected in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm  developing a site with codeigniter that support multilanguage. When a user search with their native language I got the first result when I paginate the result the  character is not decoding.

This is the url which is used to paginate.

[image]

When I print the uri segment I got %E0%B4%AE

I tried the url encode and url decode that time I got a different charecter like à´®

Can any one tell me how can I decode this type of charecterset?

Comment: there are other encoders and decoders like base64_decode and rawurldecode

Comment: first u need to tell which encoder u r using.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `urldecode` is what you should be using, the reason that you are getting the wrong output printed is probably because the output page's encoding hasn't been set to UTF-8, and is thus defaulting to ISO-8859-1. Hence, while the characters have been decoded correctly by PHP, the browser then interprets the characters in the wrong encoding, resulting in incorrect display.

To fix the problem, send a `charset` in the `Content-type` header before any output like so:

```
header('Content-type: <type>; charset=utf-8');
```

If your output page is HTML, you could alternatively use this tag in the `head`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

If you take the second option, be sure to place the tag as early as possible in the `head`, as browsers do not scan past the first 1024 bytes of the page for this declaration.

Comment: Hello Delan Azabani, my page is utf-8 i can see my articles in this language.